# How to fix width of eclipse luna toolbar buttons in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

[image: eclipse toolbar]

As you can see the buttons in the toolbar are huge. I am using eclipse luna 4.4 on linux mint 16 (ubuntu based).

I tried finding the appropriate css in the org.eclipse.ui.themes folder but nothing seemed to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in ubuntu 14 (linux mint 17).